# NLog configuration with additional project

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, nlog

In my solution there's a main project which uses NLog and there's another small  (independent) project that its purpose is to allow updating properties of the `<nlog>` section in the solution configuration file. (SolutionName.exe.config)

I created classes that inherit from ConfigurationElement, ConfigurationElementCollection and ConfigurationSection to be able to read and write into the config file.

I have to define the NLog section in the config file, otherwise NLog won't work.
My configuration file looks like this:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" /> <- need to remove this to make it work
  <section name="nlog" type="ReadWriteConfig.NLogSection, ReadWriteConfig" />
</configSections>
```

I can't allow ReadWriteConfig to reference NLog, its a standalone application.

If I run ReadWriteConfig this way, it throws an exception that it can't find the NLog assembly. If I remove the NLog `<section>` it works fine.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"somepath\SolutionName.exe.config";

// Get current configuration file.
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

NLogSection myUrlsSection = config.GetSection("nlog") as NLogSection;
```

What's the proper way dealing with the configuration file?

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do.  Is ReadWriteConfig supposed to read/write NLog config values from NLog's ConfigurationSection?  Why do you have two config sections with the same name ("nlog")?  Also, I don't know your requirements, but NLog does not require itself to be configured in the application's config file.  You could configure NLog via the NLog.config file.

Comment: wageoghe sorry the formatting was bad. There were missing tags. What I'm trying to do is change the nlog/targets and nlog/rules sections in the config file from a standalone application. I prefer having all my settings in one place..

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467027/how-to-get-same-config-section-in-two-different-assemblies